# Finding the Maclaurin Series from a power series

Tags: power-series

> I have a Power Series of: $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty = \frac{nx^{3n}}{8n}$

I need to work backwards to find the original Maclaurin Series for $\int f(x)dx$.

I'm not sure how to go on about this, do I integrate each separately?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is your power series not simplified: I see the n in both the numerator and denominator. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the power series is as given. I need to work from that. @gdepaul

Comment: @User426190: sorry, but this is hard to believe.

Comment: Would the power series have to simplified for this to work? @YvesDaoust.

Comment: @User426190: it doesn't matter but such a formula is quite unlikely.

Comment: Is this solvable? I am having trouble.

Comment: Is that series for f(x)?

Comment: @martycohen: Yes, I need to find the original $f(x)$ for the power series.